# Djava.library.path= On Eclipse.ini

Tags: linux, eclipse, slackware

I just changed my distro from ubuntu to slackware but my eclipse folder, wich was at the /home partition is still the same, I did not format it.

It has a -Djava.library.path=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/jni/ on eclipse.ini but this directory does not exist.

How can I update that to my slack? The path is looking for what? The jre?
Do I need to change anything else on eclipse.ini?

Answer (score 0):

This path is used to lookup native libraries which is required by native methods.

Comment: Any idea where the native libs stay on slack?